# What needs to be done to import and use a Linux kernel module in python?

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, twisted, kernel

What do I need to do import a Linux kernel module into python so that I can use its features in an application I want to build.

My target is to use the Better Approach To Mobile Ad-Hoc Networking (B.A.T.M.A.N) kernel module that has been included in the Linux Kernel since 2.6 for routing purposes for a mesh network that would consist of Raspberry Pis. I will be using Twisted for all the network programming.

Comment: I think you need to build a python c-extension.

Comment: -1: This question as written shows some confusion about what kernel modules are and how they are used. Modules are usually loaded during the userspace boot process from the "rc" (startup) scripts using ``udev``. Additional modules that you want that are not confugured during device probing can be loaded in ``/etc/modules.d``. See ``man modules.d``. From a Python script running as root you can do something like ``call(["modprobe", "my_module"])`` to load a module, but it's usually not a good idea to run as root unless you are on and embedded system with no user access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to load a kernel module. Kernel modules have many extremely odd properties (for example, some instructions are compiled as no-ops, then replaced at load time depending on the processor.)

Instead, it will be much simpler to *re-compile* the code into a user-space library that you can call from Python.

Even simpler still, you could just grab the "user-space" branch of the BATMAN algorithm, called batmand and use that. http://www.open-mesh.org/projects/open-mesh/wiki/BranchesExplained

Answer (score 0):

Trigger loading of that module into the kernel. Loading this into a user-space process is probably futile. In theory, you can build a Python module in C using the sources for the kernel module, but that still doesn't give you e.g. hardware access and you will have to emulate/copy large parts of the kernel infrastructure, too. Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: So basically I should write a Shell script that would be invoked on the system to load that module into the kernel? And how would Python be able to use it?

Comment: You can directly start modprobe or similar tools, no need for a shell script. Check out the subprocess module.